# How can I sort select options in jQuery to also respect each options data attributes?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a jQuery sorting function to sort select options, but it looks like it doesn't updates each options data attribute. I cannot figure it out why not. How could I fix this? (I think my function might uses old values or updates array values dynamically, not sure)

```
sortSelectOptions: function (options){
        var arr = options.map(function (_, o) {
            var val = o.value;
            var datafields = $(o).data();

            return {t: $(o).text(), v: val, d:datafields,s:$(o).is(':selected')};
        }).get();
        arr.sort(function (o1, o2) {
           return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
        });
        options.each(function (i, o) {
            o.value = arr[i].v;
            $(o).text(arr[i].t);
            $(o).data(arr[i].d);
            $(o).prop("selected",arr[i].s);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is partially working. `data` is actually copied to the other `option` tags. They are not visible when you inspect elements to find data-* attributes.

> Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in
> the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.

The not-working part is that you are adding `data` to the `option` tags, if the destination `option` has existing data with other names, they won't be removed.

There is an easier method to sort these option tags, instead of changing them, you can move them.

```
function sortSelectOptions(options) {
  options.sort((a, b) => $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text()));
  options.each((index, option) => {
    $(option).parent().append($(option));
  });
};
```

jQuery `append` the option to parent again basically move it to the end, doing it for every option and they are sorted.

```js
const sortSelectOptions = (options) => {
  options.sort((a, b) => $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text()));
  options.each((index, option) => {
    $(option).parent().append($(option));
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  sortSelectOptions($('option'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option data-a="a">B</option>
  <option data-a="b" data-c="ac">A</option>
  <option data-a="x" data-c="v">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Looks like I have overcomplicated it a bit :)